# ratchet ui css is not working in windows phone 8

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8

I have built an mobile app for windows phone 8 using phonegap 2.7 the ratchet ui  and angularjs. As far everything works fine on android build. but in windows build it gives me white black screen I think ratchet css is not working in windows phone 8 I have console output in debug mode where pages are navigated

Comment: Just trying the Ratchet CSS in IE11, I have a sneaking suspicion it probably wouldn't fly so well in the mobile IE distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone 8 is not supported by Ratchet at this point. You might want to check some related issues and give your feedback:

https://github.com/twbs/ratchet/issues/263

https://github.com/twbs/ratchet/issues/563

https://github.com/twbs/ratchet/issues/540

I would also love that Ratchet gives support to this OS

Comment: I am waiting for its support for WP8 as well